# Can I put arguments in my Fragments constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

So I have a fragment like this:

```
class MyFragment(val thing: SomeDataObject) : Fragment {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // do stuff using `thing`
    }

}
```

And I create and attach it like this:

```
val myFragment = MyFragment(SomeDataObject())

supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.contentFrame, myFragment)
    .commit()
```

Where I take a variable `thing` as a parameter - this seems to work, however everything I read about passing arguments to fragments says to do it by creating a bundle and setting `arguments` on the fragment instance.

Is there something wrong with doing it the way I defined above or some kind of benefit to using bundles instead?

Just curious as to why everywhere else suggests using seemingly over complicated ways of passing the arguments...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fragments need to have a 0-arg constructor so the framework can recreate them for you e.g. after a configuration change. You'll get a crash if the 0-arg constructor is missing. If you have both 0-arg and >0-arg constructors, any init done in the >0-arg one will be missing when the 0-arg constructor is invoked.

Comment: How come i haven't faced this issue yet? Been using the method I defined for awhile and have not gotten any crashes - is there something i can do to produce the issue you described?

Comment: Screen rotation is an easy way to cause a config change.

Comment: Awesome thanks, was able to reproduce it - will accept your answer when im allowed to

Comment: @laalto What if I don't have a screen rotation in my application? Can I use the constructor?

Comment: @Master There are other ways to trigger configuration changes, and if you use a custom constructor then you're essentially pointing at your foot with a loaded gun. 0-arg constructor or FragmentFactory is the only correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Android also allows to set [FragmentFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentFactory), which will be responsible for instantiating Fragments.

Using fragmentFactory makes sure necessary dependency particularly when dependency is not of primary types and can be put into bundle and set to fragment args.

This also prevents run time exception for activity recreate scenario (screen rotation/screen-zoom etc.)

Can look at [this](https://www.techyourchance.com/fragmentfactory-android/) tutorial on how to use a fragmentFactory for parametrized fragment constructor scenario.