# Is the way i am creating fragments in my android app properly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-management, android-developer-api

I'm developing an android java app that is like a survey with more than 100 questions. The user can see each question at a time so for each question I make a fragment that pass one by one, let´s call it QuestionFragment
Sometimes when  user is around the 50th question the app chrashes and restore with problems. Seems to be a memory problem. The way I'm creating fragments is this code:

```
QuestionFragment nvofrag = new QuestionFragment(nvoReac,false);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.continf_fragment, nvofrag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This code is inside QuestionFargment and it is called in the "next question" button so the question is Am I creating the fragments properly? Is my programming logic correct?
I hope to be clear. Any idea or comment how to google my problem could be for help.

Comment: So you have 100 Fragment class???

Comment: Hi Skizo Yes, I think so. What I wanted to do is to create a totally new fragment when the users push "next question" button and destroy previous fragment.

Comment: So...100 Fragments is a lot, but...with replace, it shouldn't be enough to crash an app, unless you've got something else causing a memory leak.  What is the crash message in logcat?

Comment: Also [don't pass arguments in the constructor like that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65514124/208273).  But that's not your problem here.

Comment: @Ryan M
There's no crash message, but sometimes the app closes and restore, so I think is about memory leak. I think as fragments passes one to another, previous is destroyed

Comment: See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](/q/23353173) for advice on how to get the crash message.

Comment: (in other words: if it *is* a memory leak, there should be a crash message in the logs)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your problem correctly and I don't know if you have 100 fragments, if so, of course it can lead to memory issues and performance problems due the amount of `Fragments` created.

What I recommend is to have just one `Fragment` for the survey and dynamically populate the questions based on a data source, JSON, whatever and inside that `Fragment` have a `ViewPager` or `RecyclerView`.

### Pseudo code

In the `Activity` create the instance of your `ViewPager`

```
ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
QuestionPagerAdapter adapter = new QuestionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then your `QuestionPagerAdapter` should be like this

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    QuestionFragment fragment = new QuestionFragment();
    fragment.setQuestion(questionList.get(position));
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return questionList.size(); //Assuming you have a list of questions
}
```

<del>Then in your *single `Fragment`* have a method of `setQuestion`</del>

<del>```
public void setQuestion(Question question) {
    this.question = question;
}
```</del>

Use [`bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment/9245510#9245510) to pass data to the `Fragment`

And in the `onCreateView` do the logic to show the `Question` and move to the next question

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);
    logicToPrintQuestion();

    //logic to change the question
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(....)
    //Here add the answer to a list if you want
    //Using the viewPager to change the 
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);

    return view;
}
```

This may not compile but it's an idea of how would be *one possible* implementation.

### Edit

You are right, `ViewPager` you can swipe between them, what you can do is create a custom `ViewPager` as :

```
class NonSwipeableViewPager(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ViewPager(context, attrs) {
    
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }
    
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

So in your `xml` should be :

```
<com.yourpackage.appname.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your intresting and help. As you can see I'm not expirienced in android developer, I think viewpager creates kind of tabs, but what i need is the user must answer one question to pass next and user just see one question at a time

Comment: As I can understand you, that custom viewpager could help with questions transition and the ui layout in one fragment? If so let me try it.

Comment: The viewpager won't let you move through the questions manually, it only will work when you programmatically change the question, so I guess is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, you've go it perfect.  I've asked that because my main problem at first was how to make the view dinamically because the questions sometimes needs spinners, another times edittext, another to take a photo and so on

Comment: Excuse me, would you tell me please if with the adapter solution there is not creating 100 items or that class is like recyclerview which manages the creation?

Comment: There's something in your Fragment should have the Logic to show the desired View, or if you know that there are just 3/4 types, you can create the ViewPager with the Fragment you want.

Comment: You can add `RecyclerView` to a `ViewPager` here https://developersbreach.com/recyclerview-to-viewpager2-materialviewpager-android/